# How can retrieve data from a SQL server using a html form?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm looking at creating a form where user can enter their details if they have forgotten their password. I was wondering if it is possible to use the SQL database I have used to see if the data entered in the form matches what is on the Database.

Is there a way that I can do this using visual studio?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hei, I think you are working on an ASP.net project, there is tons of documentation present about your question. I suggest you, to follow the following tutorial:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-sql-database-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp-and-insert-and-view-the-data-usi/